# How can I get TaxACT 2013 to run on Debian Wheezy amd64 with Wine 1.4?

Tags: wine

What can I do to run TaxACT 2013 under Wine 1.4.1 on Debian Wheezy amd64?

Running TaxACT[enter link description here](http://www.taxact.com/tax-preparation/) from a terminal gives this:

```
$ env WINEPREFIX="/home/bill/.wine" wine "C:\TaxACT\TAXA~SPJ\TaxACT13.exe" 
fixme:ieframe:PersistStreamInit_InitNew (0x14f2a8)
fixme:ieframe:WebBrowser_put_RegisterAsDropTarget (0x14f2a8)->(0)
...
```

Wine also produces a backtrace that starts

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x0075a7d0).
```

I can provide more details, if it's helpful.

I did install the i386 version of gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so manually to get this far.

FWIW, the 2012 version fails, too, but the 2011 version seems to work.

Does the fixme:ieframe:... suggest something obvious?

Comment: vaab's comment on http://askubuntu.com/questions/127848/wine-cant-find-gnome-keyring-pkcs11-so shows how I installed gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so .

Comment: Searching the wine appdb, it does not appear as if TaxACT is running in wine at all, not 2011 or 2012. No test results for 2013. I think your best option is to run windows in a VM or dual boot.

Comment: I filed a report a few days ago for 2013, but it got deleted.  I see 2012 as bronze (I rated it); it worked for me.  In fact, I've used TaxACT on wine for perhaps 8 years or so.  Each year seems to have a few issues, but the serious ones get resolved easily.  I just don't yet know what to do about this year's version.

Comment: Those errors suggest the application is using IE functions that have not been fully implemented in Wine yet- have you tried installing IE7 in your Wine environment using Winetricks? http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks

Comment: Thanks.  I'm running winetricks  20130707.  I run winetricks as me, select "Install an app" from the menu, and don't see any option to install ie*.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I got that to work.  Starting TaxACT in the same WINEPREFIX gets me two "Internet Explorer Script Error" dialogs and errors starting with $ env WINEPREFIX="/home/me/.wine" wine "C:\TaxACT\TAXA~SPJ\TaxACT13.exe"
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x2c49f97, 0x2d84b08, {3e1fd72a-c323-4574-9917-5ce9c936f78c}, 1, 0x32d228, (null), (null), 0x2d84b10,): stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x2c49f97, 0x2d84b28, {afff9c82-5be3-4205-9b3e-49e014c09a63}, 1, 0x32d228, (null), (null), 0x2d84b30,): stub
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW Option INTERNET_OPTION_RESET_URLCACHE_SESSION: STUB

Comment: Solved (I think): I used PlayOnLinux to install Wine 1.7.9, and now TaxACT 2013 seems to work.  It even imported last year's return, which I haven't seen work in a few years.

Comment: This claims that it has worked well under some testing, and gives some installation instructions: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1265

Comment: For anyone dropping by here more recently, I gave up trying in 2016 and switched to the free, cross-platform OpenTaxSolver.